# AngularJS Serial on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="product in ProductList" ng-show="ProductList.length >=1">
<h3> Product {{ProductList.length + 1}}</h3>
```

All i need to do is show in the `h3` a serial number e.g.

```
Product 1
Product 2
....
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$index`, see [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="product in ProductList">
    <h3>Product {{$index + 1}}</h3>
</div>
```

You don't need `ngShow` since `ngRepeat` won't iterate an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just want the position/ordinal of the `product` inside `ProductList` (i.e. `ProductList.indexOf(product) + 1`), or some unique identifier stored on the `product` variable.  Here is how you would do both:

`<h3> Product {{$index + 1}}</h3>`

or

`<h3> Product {{product.serial}}</h3>`

---

To address a commenter's concerns, if you have some complicated scoping issues , such as a nested `ng-repeat` (you didn't, so I assumed you didn't), the most clear way to express that intent would be:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in ProductList" ng-init="serial = $index">
...
<h3> Product {{serial}}</h3>
```

But I wouldn't introduce another variable (i.e. `serial`) until you need to. `$index` will be what most people are expecting for an `ng-repeat` that doesn't do some crazy scope creation inside.

Comment: sometimes $index will cause prolem is another scope inject withing ng-repeat

Comment: I don't think `ng-show="ProductList.length >=1"` is needed..`$index` should work too...